# Error check kicks in even before entire value is entered in an edit box

Tags: delphi

I have two edits boxes on a form, one for a min value and the other for a max value that the user needs to enter.  I want to catch possible errors as the user is entering the values.  One  possible error is that the max value is less than the min value.  I bring up a error message if this happens.  However, even if the user wants to enter a 5 in the min box and a 100 in the max box, it brings up the error message even as the user is entering the "1" of the 100 in the max box if he has already entered a 5 in the min box.  How to allow the user to enter the entire value before bringing up the error message?

Here is my code (i catch other errors too, but only max < min error seems to be affected):

```
procedure TfrmAnalysisOptions.lbleConstraintsMaxChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: integer;
  Val, ValidEntry: string;
  Chr: char;
  RangeMin, RangeMax: Double;
  const Allowed = ['0'..'9', '.'];
begin

  Val := lbleConstraintsMax.Text;

      //initialize values    
  ValidEntry := '';
  ConstraintsMaxChange := '';

  //value can contain only numerals, and "."
    for I := 1 to Length(Val) do
     begin
       Chr := Val[I];
       if not (Chr in Allowed) then
       begin
     MessageDlgPos('The value entered for the max value of the ' +
               'constraint must contain only a numeral, a decimal ' +
               'point or a negative sign.',
            mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);
     Exit;

       end
       else ValidEntry := 'OK'; //validity check for this part

     end;

     //max value cannot be zero or less than the min value
    if not TryStrToFloat(Val, RangeMax) then Exit
    else if RangeMax = 0 then
    begin
       MessageDlg('Max value cannot be zero.', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
       Exit;
    end
    else if not TryStrToFloat(lbleConstraintsMin.Text, RangeMin) then Exit
    else if RangeMax < RangeMin then
      begin
    MessageDlgPos('Max value cannot be less than Min value.',
           mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);
    Exit;
      end

    else if (RangeMax < 0) then
      begin
    MessageDlgPos('A constraint cannot be negative.',
              mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);
    Exit;
      end

    //final validity check
    else if ValidEntry = 'OK' then ConstraintsMaxChange := 'OK'
    else MessageDlgPos('There was an unexpected problem with the ' +
               'value entered in the max constraints box.',
            mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);

end;
```

Comment: The [`TMaskEdit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Mask.TMaskEdit) component allows for masking input characters. A mask `###.#` stops anything but numbers and decimal character.

Comment: Thanks, @LURD.  Let me check on that, for the minus sign is valid too.

Comment: [`#`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.MaskUtils.TEditMask) allows for a sign as well.

Comment: @LURD Is there a difference between `###.#` and `#.#`?

Comment: @JerryDodge, from doc: `"The # character permits a numeric character or a plus or minus sign in this position, but doesn't require it."`. If at least one numeric character is required before the decimal character, a `0` can be put into the mask before the decimal character.

Comment: @LURD Understood, but that's not quite what I mean. Wouldn't `###.#` do the exact same thing as `#.#`?

Comment: @JerryDodge, only if the maximum number is `9.9`.

Comment: @JerryDodge, there is a popup menu for entering the mask in the IDE. It's possible to test the mask there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `OnChange` event is triggered every time the contents of your edit controls have been modified. While this is the appropriate place to filter out invalid characters, it's not the appropriate place to validate the numeric values. There is no way to predict what number the user intends to type, whether `5`, `50`, `500`, `5,000`, where each of those may or may not be acceptable.

**Solution 1**: Do this check after both these edit controls have been filled out and the user attempts to go to the next step (save, continue, load, start, etc.).

**Solution 2**: Rather than showing a message box, you can show a label next to these controls that says "Invalid entry" while keeping your same logic. That way the user won't be confronted by numerous message boxes.

**Solution 3**: Use the `OnExit` event instead of `OnChange`. Note that this will not completely resolve your issue, but minimize it. This event triggers when the focus leaves a control.

**Solution 4** Similar to Solution 2, use `OnChange` and `OnExit` to control the `Enabled` property of the button which the user would presumably press next.

**Solution 5** Similar to Solution 4, use Actions and change the `Enabled` property of that particular action. Then, any button which the user may press cannot be clicked.

---

On a side note, when you're filtering out invalid characters, it's a bit more elegant to just ignore these characters and don't let them into the controls in the first place, rather than popping up a message. You can accomplish this by using the `OnKeyPress` event instead, or by using a [`TMaskEdit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Mask.TMaskEdit).

Comment: Consider using `OnExit` for validation rather than `OnChange`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I was going to mention that, but OP would face similar issues since there are two fields being validated against each other.

Comment: I mean imagine the fields are already set to `0` .. `100` and user attempts to change it to `200` .. `500`. If using `OnExit`, the same issue would arise, unless the Max was changed before the Min.

Comment: I do the validation at both OnChange and OnExit.  Let me check out the OnKeyPress event.  I presume you mean I use OnKeyPress instead of either the OnChange or OnExit events?

Comment: @user1505202 The `OnKeyPress` is directed as a side note for your other validation of numbers, which was only a suggestion. For your actual issue, refer to my first paragraph.

Comment: The "next step" really is when the user tries to save the form with all the entries on it.  I can do a validation there, but I would like to be able to validate the entry even as it is being made for each edit box.  Which is where I thought your OnKeyPress might do the job....

Comment: @user1505202 Well in your case there would be no difference between `OnKeyPress` and `OnChange` - you would have the exact same behavior.

Comment: @user1505202 The event you are looking for is the `OnExit()` event of the editboxes. It is only triggered when the editbox looses focus so there might be a value validation routine, but it even holds the danger Jerry Dodge pointed out.

Comment: @mg30rg: I already do the validation on OnChange as well as the OnExit events for each edit box.  The problem I am facing cannot be unique.  How to code such that the entire value is entered in the edit box before the error message is triggered?  TEditMask will not do it because I am validating one edit box against another.

Comment: Just read the recent comments of @Jerry. I guess I am not following what the "next step" means.  If you mean pressing the "Save" button, yes, I do the validation then too, but I want the user to become aware of the mistake **when it occurs** too.  I am not sure how showing a red label would be different from raising the `messageDlg` in terms of being able to make a complete entry into the max edit box without triggering the error notification (red label, in this case).

Comment: @user1505202 Imagine the user wishes to type `5000`. They press the `5` and they get an error window. Then they press `0` and another error window. Then two more times, 2 more error windows. Do you really want your users to see so many error windows? I would suggest solution 2, where you can keep your current validation, except instead of showing a dialog, just put a small label next to these fields. If it's valid, hide the label. If it's invalid, show the label. That simple.

Comment: @Jerry: I see.  So instead of the error message, the label continues to show until the max value exceeds the min value.  Yes, that is better. Let me try that.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I must not have explained it well enough in my answer, updating

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach to either OnExit or OnChange, may I suggest an object oriented pattern approach:

1. Define model objects.  `TMyBusinessModelObject = class ....`
2. Define a function in your View object that copies data to your model object.
3. Do your validation in your model object.
4. If it makes sense, kick the validation off when you need it, which is when the modal dialog closes.  If you need to display a color code on the screen, such as an image or a status indicator, then use `OnExit` events.
5. Write unit tests so you know your model object, and your viewmodel or controller objects work, and that your business logic works.

Secondly, even better than a `TMaskEdit` or a `TEdit` where you write code to block invalid characters, there are controls in the JVCL designed specifically for Numeric input, including ones that let you input constraints right at the control level.

Delphi is a component-oriented RAD tool, and when you use it like one, and when you avoid the code-behind-form (Big Ball of Mud) right from the start, you won't have a giant mess to clean up later.  (A rather sad truth is that Standard Delphi practice is to do the simplest thing that could possibly work, and build a giant ball of mud, with no OOP.)

Comment: I'm sure there is more than a grain of wisdom in what you say.  However, I am unfortunately too much of a beginner to grasp the details of your suggestion.  A suggestion by Jerry Dodge worked for me, and for now I will have to leave it at that.  Perhaps one day I will learn to program better.  Thanks anyway,a nd I appreciate your input.

Comment: Just to clarify for those who don't know, "RAD" stands for "Rapid Application Development". It's a rad acronym too.

Comment: Or go even a step further and encapsulate particular business rule inside of DLL's, for example `MyDatabase.dll`, `MyCommon.dll`, `MyUsers.dll`, `MyEncryption.dll`, and so on - which is what I'm in the process of doing myself, building a large software infrastructure from the ground up little pieces at a time. It is a big deal and requires a lot of knowledge - but when you get most of these concepts down, everything becomes even easier.

Comment: Well, it is clear that I have a lot to learn from you folks.  Thanks for being so helpful!